# MySQL sort by zip code and then random in each zip code

Tags: mysql, sorting, random

I have an SQL query that I am running which is:

```
SELECT * FROM listings, listings_categories 
    WHERE listings.id = listings_categories.listing_id AND category_id 
    IN (1,3,5,8,7,4,5,2) 
    AND business_zip IN (89101,89102,89103,89104,89105,89106) 
    AND status = '1' GROUP BY listings.id
```

Would there be a way to sort the results so that it sorted by business_zip ASC but randomize the results within each zip code or am I better off handling this in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple sorts..

```
SELECT * FROM listings, listings_categories 
WHERE listings.id = listings_categories.listing_id AND category_id 
IN (1,3,5,8,7,4,5,2) 
AND business_zip IN (89101,89102,89103,89104,89105,89106) 
AND status = '1' GROUP BY listings.id
ORDER BY business_zip, RAND()
```

Comment: Oh nice... I thought that if you used RAND() after another sort parameter that it cancelled out the other parameter. I will give this a go.

Comment: I don't think so, it should act exactly the same as if there was a column called 'rand' in the table which was pre-filled with random values between 0 and <1. For extra fun you can add a 'weight' column to the database and multiply it by rand to weight the results towards specific rows. `ORDER BY business_zip, RAND()*weight`